# How to load a page with jquery on a different domain, I have set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tags: jquery

I have set

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

but I am still unable to

```
$('element').load('http://....')
```

a page on the domain I have set the

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

on, Any ideas on why I am still unable to load that page using jQuery?

Comment: Why are you trying to load another website into your page? This is generally restricted for security reasons. There are ways, but the motivation here is questionable, which is why I am hesitant to answer...

Comment: I am creating a widget, a plugin for wordpress, that uses my service, on that widget, I am placing a link for help, I would like that to show up in a pop up, I am already making post requests to my server, and those work, however, a simple, .load is refusing to load the html

Comment: Are you also sending `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST` header?

Comment: Try returning your help documentation as JSON from your site and using `file_get_contents('http://yoursite.com/help.php')` in your plugin, and `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest')` with `json_encode()` on your site on the query result, assuming the help data on your site is being pulled from a database. Or, simply put an `iframe` in your plugin's popup.

Comment: Actually, that is a bit much in terms of webpage hits, I think I am going to go with a caching option for the widget host to cache the page once a day or something like that

Comment: @jlroberts you might also want to look at Cloudflare for caching and saving HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add in the line `$.support.cors = true;` before the load request, it will force jQuery to approve cross-domain requests.

Comment: Hrmmm, I just put that on the line before the load, without success, I am using jQuery version, 1.5.2

Comment: @jlroberts just iframe it and use a cache, or return the data from your site as JSON.